# How to create vertical "pages" where each page is height of the viewport using Bootstrap and Angular?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Angular 1.3 and Bootstrap 3.2.  I want to create a single webpage that does exactly this: http://lewisking.net.  i.e.  I want to be able to have vertically stacked divs that are the height of the viewport.  I'm thinking of making a directive that watches the browser height/width and updates the style accordingly.

Any other ideas?  Any tips for implementing with a directive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the perfect use case for `vh` and `vw`.

Simply set:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

And it will work out the box. If you have to support any [old browsers](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units) you can easily do a quick JS fall back.

Comment: Works, thanks. Would your JS fallback check the browser type/version?

Comment: I would personally use Modernizr to check for compatibility. If you feel that's over kill, a very dirty hack would be to add !important to your VH/VW, that way if the browser cannot detect VH/VW it will be ignored and JavaScripts H/W will take precedent. But, I can't recommend that, you should really be using Modernizr for feature detection as a best practice! Let me know if you need any further help!

Answer (score 1):

CSS will get you part of the way, but you will need JS to update your 100% height on resize
and scrollTop points etc. And you will also need a way to animate the scroll anyway.  This isn't exactly what I would do but it explains the basic idea.

```
$($window).on('resize', function() {
   $scope.winWidth = $(window).width();
   $scope.winHeight = $(window).height();
});

...

$scope.getSectionStyle = function(){
  return {width:$scope.winWidth, height:$scope.winHeight} ;
}

...

<section id="sectionId" ng-style="getSectionStyle()"
```

To animate the scroll I just use jQuery like. If you're a angular purist there is $achorScoll but it has no animating at this point so you need to do some extra factory or directive like https://github.com/durated/angular-scroll/

```
$rootScope.scrollTo = function(_to){
    $("html, body").delay(300).animate({scrollTop:_to},{ easing: "easeOutExpo"}, 2000);
}
```

To get `_to` you just find the elements offset().top something like :

```
var offset = $('#sectionId').offset();
$rootScope.scrollTo(offset.top);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Actually, the CSS change with 100vh seems to work when you resize as well, but the support is only for recent browsers.  Thanks for the tip on animating the anchor scroll.